# VB.NET Dynamic Factory

Tags: vb.net

How would I change this code to make the factory dynamic. I believe I was close with remoting. I don't want any hardcoding of the factory, nor do I want to have to recompile. The database drives it.

```
Dim genericRule As Rule
Dim factoryObject As String

factoryObject = _dal.GetFactoryObject(ruleId)

'Close, but not quite will keep working on it.
'Dynamic object creation using remoting to the local computer.
'Dim mArgs(1) As Object
'mArgs(0) = ruleid
'mArgs(1) = pronumber
'Dim mObj As Object
'Try
'    mObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Nothing, "DedicatedBilling.RuleFactory." + mFactoryObject, mArgs)
'    mRule = CType(mObj, Rule)
'Catch ex As Exception
'    mObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Nothing, "DedicatedBilling.RuleFactory.ErrorRule", mArgs)
'    mRule = CType(mObj, Rule)
'End Try

Select Case factoryObject
    Case "DeadHeadEntryRule"
        genericRule = New DeadHeadEntryRule(ruleId, proNumber)
    Case "DeadHeadFuelRateRule"
        genericRule = New DeadHeadFuelRateRule(ruleId, proNumber)
    Case "DeliveryStatusRule"
        genericRule = New DeliveryStatusRule(ruleId, proNumber)

    Case Else
        genericRule = New ErrorRule(ruleId, proNumber)
End Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't post so much code. I didn't even *see* the important part of your code at first. You didn't need to list every single rule in order to get your point across.

In any case, you want to look at [Activator.CreateInstanceFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fce0hc8.aspx) and Reflection, not at Remoting.

```
' Create an instance of the SomeType class that is defined in this assembly.
Dim oh As System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle = _
    Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase, _
                                 GetType(SomeType).FullName)

' Call an instance method defined by the SomeType type using this object.
Dim st As SomeType = CType(oh.Unwrap(), SomeType)

st.DoSomething(5)
```

Comment: Thank you for the question pointer. I removed the extraneous code. I believe I tried this and couldn't figure out how to handle the fact that new is not overloaded and requires two arguments, but that was a few months ago.

Comment: @Doug: the various methods of the `Activator` class include some that allow you to pass parameters for the constructor to use.

Comment: I should be able to find the right one then I can turn the applicaion over to someone else without feeling guilty about the factory hard code.